# Chartwell fonts and changing colour with ligatures

Tags: xetex, ligatures, truetype

Bit of a niche question. There is a beautiful set of TrueType fonts called [Chartwell](https://www.fontfont.com/how-to-use-ff-chartwell) designed for producing graphs from text.
I am trying to get these to work in Latex.
I have switched to Xe(La)tex, and can now get the fonts to appear.
However I would like to change text colour without sequence of numbers being split into two.
Best explained with some code and a picture.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Now define your quick commands for switching fonts
\setmainfont{ChartwellRose}
\newfontfamily\cwrose[Ligatures=Rare, Color=blue]{ChartwellRose}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

Here is the text without ligatures

\fontsize{48}{60}
\selectfont
40+20+50
\rmfamily
\normalsize


Here is the text with ligatures

\cwrose
\fontsize{48}{60}
\selectfont
40+70
\rmfamily
\normalsize

Here is the text with a colour change inserted

\cwrose
\fontsize{48}{60}
\selectfont
40+\addfontfeature{Color=red}+70
\rmfamily
\normalsize

And as you can see the colour change has broken the effect of enabling the ligatures and the 'rose' is now presented as two separate objects (rather than a single object with 2 different colours.

\end{document}
```

Is it possible therefore to change the colour of a part of the text without the ligature formation being broken?

Here is a [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/MbXL) of the compiled example and here is a [screenshot](http://d.pr/i/3Fq4) of unbroken form of the last example

Comment: Not in XeTeX, color will always break text flow and hence the ligatures, and `\addfontfeature` just defines a new font from the current one plus the requested features.  Possible with LuaTeX though, if you are interested in LuaTeX solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. At least I know to stop looking. I'll leave the question open just a little longer in case someone else has an alternative suggestion.

Comment: So I have just discovered the [sparklines](http://ctan.org/pkg/sparklines) package. Should have worked out that many of the things that Chartwell does can already be done in latex. Will use these instead of chartwell!

Answer (score 10):

I can confirm that FF Chartwell works as intended using the `luacolor` package.

**Edit:**
As requested by Stephan here is a MWE. This is for luatex only (so this is a workaround rather than a complete answer to the question by drstevok).

```
\documentclass{article}

%Fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec}

%CHARTWELL (Be sure to load style set 1, otherwise the ligatures won't be activated.)
\newfontface\cwp[StylisticSet={1}]{ChartwellPies}
\newfontface\cwr[StylisticSet={1}]{ChartwellRose}
\newfontface\cwb[StylisticSet={1}]{ChartwellBars}
\newfontface\cwbv[StylisticSet={1}]{ChartwellBarsVertical}
%etc.


%COLORS (Works exactly the same as the regular latex color package.}
\usepackage{luacolor}
\definecolor{aut1}{RGB}{255,51,0}
\definecolor{aut2}{RGB}{255,102,0}
\definecolor{aut3}{RGB}{255,153,0}
\definecolor{aut4}{RGB}{255,204,0}
\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fontsize{100}{120}
\cwp \textcolor{aut1}{24}+\textcolor{aut2}{31}+\textcolor{aut3}{40}+\textcolor{aut4}{5}+\textcolor{white}{A}\\
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fontsize{100}{120}
\cwr\textcolor{aut1}{14}+\textcolor{aut2}{30}+\textcolor{aut3}{12}+\textcolor{aut4}{44}+\textcolor{white}{A}\\
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fontsize{100}{120}
\cwb \textcolor{red}{50}+\textcolor{blue}{31}+\textcolor{green}{19}\textcolor{aut4}{=}\\
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fontsize{100}{120}
\cwbv \textcolor{red}{50}+\textcolor{blue}{31}+\textcolor{green}{19}\\
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: example ff chartwell latex]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I assume this will requite LUATeX? Could you reconstruct the MWE from the question so that it will work with LuaTeX?

Answer (score 5):

This can’t be done in XeTeX, color will always break text flow and hence the ligatures, and `\addfontfeature` just defines a new font from the current one plus the requested features, and inter-font ligatures will not work of course. It might be possible with LuaTeX though when using the `luacolor` package.

Comment: How about with `\font\foo="Some Font:color=DDFFAA"`?

Comment: @morbusg: Not sure how that is can help with the situation described here?

Comment: I'm not sure either, I was just thinking of something like: `\def\f{Courier:color}\font\r="\f=DD0000"\font\g="\f=00DD00"\font\b="\f=0000DD"\r15+\g32+\b18\bye`, But I realized that the font-change is probably going to kill the ligas as well.

Comment: Right, there can’t be any inter-font ligatures (and `\addfontfeature` basically does that, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

New user here, so I cannot comment under the David Carlisle answer.

He had:

```
%CHARTWELL (Be sure to load style set 1, otherwise the ligatures won't be activated.)
\newfontface\cwp[StylisticSet={1}]{ChartwellPies}
```

Travis Kochel, the creator of Chartwell, emailed me directly to say that `ss01` and `[StylisticSet={1}]` were for older versions of Chartwell.

Instead use discretionary ligatures:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Discretionary}}
\newfontface\cwp{ChartwellPies}
```

This works for me under LuaLaTeX like it does in the David Carlisle MWE.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/254302)